# Symfony Assert on integer field strange behaviour

Tags: php, validation, symfony, assert

I've got an integer field within my entity that i want to validate on a positive integer value:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @Assert\Range(min=1)
 */
protected $size;
```

The form type for this is :

```
 ->add('size', 'integer', array())
```

I get strange / unexpected results when i enter:

- nothing:           This value should not be blank
- negative integer:  This value should be 1 or more
- text:              This value should not be blank
- double value:      accepted
- integer value:     accepted

What i would expect / want:

- nothing:           This value should not be blank
- negative integer:  This value should be 1 or more
- text:              **This value should be an integer**
- double value:      **This value should be an integer**
- integer value:     accepted

Hope you can help me, 
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

for text:

```
->add('size', 'integer', array(
    'invalid_message' => 'This value should be an integer',
))
```

For double, that is not accepted(that use [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) function).

but you can use a regex with pattern: \d+

Comment: Nop that did not help. I switched now to form type 'number', seems as if 'integer' is not working as it should within the validation .. now it's working .